# uwsgi + django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myproject'

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, uwsgi

Я пытаюсь запустить django проект с помощью uwsgi и nginx.

Возникает ошибка при запуске uwsgi: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lawyer'

Структура проекта:

```
lawyer/
  ...
  ...
  manage.py
  ...
  lawyer/
    __init__.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    uwsgi.py
  

  GNU nano 4.8           /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= lawyer.settings.production
#wsgi-file = lawyer/wsgi.py
module = lawyer.uwsgi:application
workers = 1
max-requests = 5000
#plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
plugins = python3
#virtualenv = /root/eva/venv
pythonpath = /root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
die-on-term = true
socket = /run/sedova.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = www-data
gui = www-data
```

Лог uwsgi:

```
 Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - binary reloading uWSGI...
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - chdir() to /
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - closing all non-uwsgi socket fds > 2 (max_fd = 1024)...
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - found fd 3 mapped to socket 0 (/run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - found fd 5 mapped to socket 1 (/run/sedova.sock)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - running /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from /etc/uwsgi/apps-enabled/myapp.ini
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18-debian (64bit) on [Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022] ***
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - compiled with version: 10.0.1 20200405 (experimental) [master revision 0be9efad938:fcb98e4978a:705510a708d3642c9c962beb663c476167e4e8a4] on 11 April 2020 11:15:55
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - os: Linux-5.4.0-92-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 26 16:13:00 UTC 2021
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - nodename: 185-46-8-164.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - machine: x86_64
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - clock source: unix
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - pcre jit disabled
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - current working directory: /
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - chdir() to /root/eva/lawyer
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 2623]
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - VACUUM: pidfile removed.
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - chdir(): Permission denied [core/uwsgi.c line 1647]
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - *** Starting uWSGI 2.0.18-debian (64bit) on [Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022] ***
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - compiled with version: 10.0.1 20200405 (experimental) [master revision 0be9efad938:fcb98e4978a:705510a708d3642c9c962beb663c476167e4e8a4] on 11 April 2020 11:15:55
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - os: Linux-5.4.0-92-generic #103-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 26 16:13:00 UTC 2021
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - nodename: 185-46-8-164.cloudvps.regruhosting.ru
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - machine: x86_64
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - clock source: unix
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - pcre jit disabled
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - detected number of CPU cores: 1
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - current working directory: /
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - writing pidfile to /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/pid
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - detected binary path: /usr/bin/uwsgi-core
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - chdir() to /root/eva/lawyer
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - your processes number limit is 1831
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - your memory page size is 4096 bytes
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - detected max file descriptor number: 1024
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - uwsgi socket 0 bound to UNIX address /run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket fd 3
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - uwsgi socket 1 bound to UNIX address /run/sedova.sock fd 5
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - setgid() to 33
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - setuid() to 33
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - Python version: 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08)  [GCC 9.3.0]
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - Python main interpreter initialized at 0x56191037ec70
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - python threads support enabled
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - mapped 500256 bytes (488 KB) for 10 cores
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - *** Operational MODE: preforking+threaded ***
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - added /root/eva/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ to pythonpath.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lawyer'
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 26585)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 26590, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 2 (pid: 26591, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 3 (pid: 26592, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 4 (pid: 26593, cores: 2)
Tue Jan 11 13:15:59 2022 - spawned uWSGI worker 5 (pid: 26594, cores: 2)
```

Comment: current working directory: / - так и задумано?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что у Вас проект в /root/eva/ ... Наверное в него и рабочую директорию нужно бы поставить?

Comment: Проект - lawyer имеет путь /root/eva/lawyer. Я указал его в myapp.ini как chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
Его нужно было указать иначе или может в другом месте? Скажите, в чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Я попробовал изменить chdir на chdir = /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer чтобы путь вел в папку проекта где хранится settings.py и uwsgi.py. но это ничего не дало

Comment: Мне удалось избежать ошибки ModuleNotFoundError, указав параметр uwsgi-file = /full/path/to_wsgi.py, но теперь uwsgi выводит мне -  failed to open python file /root/eva/lawyer/lawyer/wsgi.py